# Getting the value of a Textbox in a TemplateField in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i'm gonna keep it short and simple
I'm a software engineering student in the 12th grade and as my final project I have decided to make a website. What the website is about doesn't really matter. The problem is this:

In the picture attached there is a textbox inside a templatefield inside that gridview. I need to get the value that the user writes inside. After you write a value you press Purchase. I've looked at similar questions and none offered a working solution. What happens is the value just disappears. I find the right control with FindControl, but the value gets deleted somehow. How do I know I am at the right control? I went to the client side and added to the asp:TextBox the following:
Text="5"
This works perfectly, so I know it gets to the right control but something makes it disappear. My gridview is being populated by a DataSet that is two datasets combined, and I put the Merge command and the DataSource and DataBind are both in if (!this.IsPostBack). I am completely lost and have no idea what to do, Help is much appreciated.[The Picture of the Gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCc1C.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

All the controls in a GridView are accessible by searching the correct row with FindControl. For that you can send the row number as a CommandArgument and use that in code behind. So first start by using `OnCommand` instead on `OnClick` and set the `CommandArgument` on the aspx page.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Purchase" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And then in code behind

```
protected void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    //get the rownumber from the command argument
    int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    //find the textbox in the corrext row with findcontrol
    TextBox tb = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;

    //get the value from the textbox
    try
    {
        int numberOfTickets = Convert.ToInt32(tb.Text);
    }
    catch
    {
        //textbox is empty or not a number
    }
}
```